# Laravel eloquent relationships Multiple table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

When I try to connect my table using a query. But I need the building relationship using Laravel eloquent.

This is my query

```
{
  
$students = Student::with('FeeScheem')
->leftJoin('fee_scheems', 'fee_scheems.fs_id', '=', 'students.stu_fee_scheem_id')
->leftJoin('individually_fee_scheems', 'individually_fee_scheems.id', '=', 'students.stu_ind_fee_scheem_id')
->leftJoin('fee_masters', 'fee_masters.fee_master_ind_fee_scheem_id', '=', 'individually_fee_scheems.id')
->leftJoin('fee_groups', 'fee_groups.fg_id', '=', 'fee_masters.fee_master_fg_id')
->leftJoin('school_fee_collectors', 'school_fee_collectors.fc_fg_id', '=', 'fee_groups.fg_id')
->where('students.stu_id', $students)
->get();
$this->students = $students;
```

}

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto So I need to build this relationship using Eloquent: Relationships..

Comment: First you need to make sure your current query is correct, what does this line do? `->where('students.stu_id', $students)` doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Psycho

I use that for filtering students by their id.

Comment: `->where('students.stu_id', $students)` this part is **wrong** otherwise show us what is the output of your current query, then we may help you convert it to eloquent